# change in props not causing re-render in react - redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react -redux app. It is working fine. But when props in one particular component updated using calling props.dispatch(), other component which is using this props is not re-rendering. I think redux is not able to identify changes in that particular prop. 
object is

```
[
   {lunch: 0, dinner: 12, breakfast: 0},
   {lunch: 1, dinner: 2, breakfast: 0}, 
   {lunch: 0, dinner: 12, breakfast: 10}
]
```

and this change to something like this

```
[
   {lunch: 0, dinner: 1, breakfast: 0},
   {lunch: 1, dinner: 2, breakfast: 0}, 
   {lunch: 0, dinner: 1, breakfast: 10}
]
```

So there are just slight changes in the object. But then this should cause re-rendering in components which are using this prop. 
But this is not the case. I have checked in the reducer, the object is changing there. 
Re-render is also called for changes in other props. Only in case of this object. it is not re-rendering. 
Any suggestions?
Edit:- 
in component-

```
this.props.dispatch({type: actions.SAVE_SELECTED_MEAL, selectedMeal: selected});
```

in reducer --

`case actions.SAVE_SELECTED_MEAL:
    return {
        ...state,
        selectedMeal: action.selectedMeal // [{lunch: id, dinner: 12, breakfast: 0}]
    }`

Comment: You need to post more code, specifically the reducer and the components which are used in your question.

Comment: I found answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer in this redux issue https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/585 
In case someone gets into a similar issue. 
Actually, I was mutating object in my component I changed code from `const selected = this.state.selectedMeal;` to `const selected = {...this.state.selectedMeal};` Now its working fine.